# Sending JMS and rollback

Tags: java, transactions, jms

I found such statement:

*If you send a JMS message from an EJB, and transaction rollback, will message be sent? (Hint: yes)*

I think that it is not correct. If you use XA transactions for JMS backend, it shall rollback sent JMS as well. Right? Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right, if a JMS message sending is in transaction; the message is sent when transaction is actually committed. This is inline with [this article](http://romanykultury.info/054.html) (an statement taken from the article as below)

> ```
> As soon as a commit call is invoked, all the messages sent until that point are packaged into a transaction and are sent out to the server.
> ```